# Compilation error upgrading from VS 2008 to VS 2015

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-2008

I get errors compiling the code below when ugrading from VS 2008 to VS2015. The code is from the com4j project. Help wanted. Thanks!

- syntax error: missing ';' before '<' missing type specifier
- int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
- 'array': ambiguous symbol
- unexpected token(s) preceding ';'

Code:

```
// Class to marshal SAFEARRAY to Java multi dimensional array
//
// itemType : array item type
// XDUCER : converter for each array item
template < VARTYPE itemType, class XDUCER >
class ToJavaMultiDimlArrayMarshaller {
    typedef array::Array<typename XDUCER::JavaType> JARRAY; // Errors here
    typedef SAFEARRAY* NativeType;
    typedef jarray JavaType;
```

Comment: Maybe removing `typename` before `XDUCER::JavaType` would help?

Comment: no, did not work. I am sorry. Too few template arguments..

Answer (score -1):

What does `VARTYPE` stand for? Is it a macro? Replacing with `class` or `typename` may help

Comment: defintion is : typedef unsigned short VARTYPE; The line above refers to a macro though: / Macro to calculate the size of the above pClipData
#define CBPCLIPDATA(clipdata)    ( (clipdata).cbSize - sizeof((clipdata).ulClipFmt) )

Comment: @OyvindFoshaug error 3 says `array` is ambiguous. Did you include multiple namespaces or classes named `array`?

Comment: That is a valid point. I will specify the relevant namespace.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the syntax. The definitions of `array`, `Array` or `SAFEARRAY` may have problems. Here is my example with simple definitions. It works fine. `typedef unsigned short VARTYPE` `typedef int SAFEARRAY` `namespace array{ template <class T> class Array{ T *t;};  }`